# I want to create a sqs queue listener using sqs-consumer library but getting some error

Tags: amazon-sqs

I have implemented a sqs-consumer file for listening to a sqs queue that is receiving messages and is implemented in some other file but while executing consumer.js file some error is occurring i.e. this.sqs.send() is not the function can anyone tell me why this error is occuring

**for sqs-consumer i write this code i already have sqs-receiver code in other file which is receiving the messages but during execution of this consumer.js file i got some error**

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const { Consumer } = require("sqs-consumer");
require("dotenv").config({ path: "./../../.env" });

//aws configuration

AWS.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: "aws-secret-key",
  accessKeyId: "access-key",
  region: "us-east-1",
});

const sqs = new AWS.SQS({ apiVersion: "2012-11-05" });

const accountId = process.env.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID;
const sqsPath = process.env.SQS_PATH;
const queueName = process.env.EXPORTLOCATIONLIST_QUEUE_NAME;
const QueueUrl = `${sqsPath}/${accountId}/${queueName}`;


const subscribe = (QueueUrl, batchSpace, visibilityTimeout) => {
  const consumer = Consumer.create({
    queueUrl: QueueUrl,
    batchSize: batchSpace || 1,
    visibilityTimeout: visibilityTimeout || undefined,
    attributeNames: ["All"],
    handleMessage: async (message) => {
      console.log(message);
    },
    sqs: sqs,
  });

  
  consumer.start()

  return consumer
};

subscribe(QueueUrl);


module.exports = {
  subscribe,
};
```

```
D:\Samplify\runner_backend\task\node_modules\sqs-consumer\dist\errors.js:47
    const sqsError = new SQSError(message);
                     ^

SQSError: SQS receive message failed: this.sqs.send is not a function
    at toSQSError (D:\Samplify\runner_backend\task\node_modules\sqs-consumer\dist\errors.js:47:22)
    at Consumer.receiveMessage (D:\Samplify\runner_backend\task\node_modules\sqs-consumer\dist\consumer.js:190:43)      
    at Consumer.poll (D:\Samplify\runner_backend\task\node_modules\sqs-consumer\dist\consumer.js:144:14)
    at Consumer.start (D:\Samplify\runner_backend\task\node_modules\sqs-consumer\dist\consumer.js:62:18)
    at subscribe (D:\Samplify\runner_backend\task\src\listeners\queue_listener.js:32:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Samplify\runner_backend\task\src\listeners\queue_listener.js:38:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1356:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1414:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1197:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Consumer instance at:
    at Consumer.emit (D:\Samplify\runner_backend\task\node_modules\sqs-consumer\dist\emitter.js:29:22)
    at Consumer.emitError (D:\Samplify\runner_backend\task\node_modules\sqs-consumer\dist\consumer.js:120:18)
    at D:\Samplify\runner_backend\task\node_modules\sqs-consumer\dist\consumer.js:170:18
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'TypeError',
  statusCode: undefined,
  retryable: undefined,
  service: undefined,
  fault: undefined,
  time: 2024-01-15T07:44:44.810Z
}

Node.js v18.19.0
PS D:\Samplify\runner_backend\task\src\listeners> node queue_listener.js
D:\Samplify\runner_backend\task\node_modules\sqs-consumer\dist\errors.js:47
    const sqsError = new SQSError(message);
                     ^

SQSError: SQS receive message failed: this.sqs.send is not a function
    at toSQSError (D:\Samplify\runner_backend\task\node_modules\sqs-consumer\dist\errors.js:47:22)
    at Consumer.receiveMessage (D:\Samplify\runner_backend\task\node_modules\sqs-consumer\dist\consumer.js:190:43)      
    at Consumer.poll (D:\Samplify\runner_backend\task\node_modules\sqs-consumer\dist\consumer.js:144:14)
    at Consumer.start (D:\Samplify\runner_backend\task\node_modules\sqs-consumer\dist\consumer.js:62:18)
    at subscribe (D:\Samplify\runner_backend\task\src\listeners\queue_listener.js:32:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Samplify\runner_backend\task\src\listeners\queue_listener.js:38:1)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1197:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Consumer instance at:
    at Consumer.emit (D:\Samplify\runner_backend\task\node_modules\sqs-consumer\dist\emitter.js:29:22)
    at Consumer.emitError (D:\Samplify\runner_backend\task\node_modules\sqs-consumer\dist\consumer.js:120:18)
    at D:\Samplify\runner_backend\task\node_modules\sqs-consumer\dist\consumer.js:170:18 {
  code: 'TypeError',
  statusCode: undefined,
  retryable: undefined,
  service: undefined,
  fault: undefined,
  time: 2024-01-15T07:45:05.188Z
}
```

`please can any one tell me why this error occurs and for the information i am using nodejs:18.19.0 version and "aws-sdk": "^2.1534.0", "sqs-consumer": "^8.1.3"`